# Are Set theoretic constructions of mathematical objects unique

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

It is generally believed that mathematics (at least a considerable portion) can be embedded in ZFC set theory. But one would wonder what this statement really means, and whether the set theoretic constructions of mathematical objects are unique. For example consider the kuratowski construction of the ordered pair and the Zermelo construction of the natural number. If the constructions assigned to these objects are not unique I could prove that $ \left( 0, 0 \right) = 2$.

$(0, 0) = \left\{\{0\}, \{0, 0\}\right\} = \left\{\{0\}, \{0\}\right\} = \left\{\{0 \}\right\}$

but from Zermelo construction

$ 2 = \{\{0\}\}$ and $ 0 = \emptyset $

Hence it seems $ 2 = (0, 0) $.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: I thought kuratowski defined the ordered pair $ (x, y) $ as $ \{\{x\}, \{x, y\}\}$

Comment: Ok. Accordingly https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers $2=\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$

Comment: No they are not. See [Benacerraf's  ‘What Numbers Could Not Be’](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/philosophy-mathematics/#WhaNumCouNot)

Comment: Thanks @MauroALLEGRANZA.

Comment: Another example is formulating real numbers - either Dedekind cuts or Cauchy sequences are used, which are pretty different superficially.